# AddData in Chart.js 2.0

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to create a double-Y-axis with `Chart.js 2.0`.
I saw in documentation that `AddData` works as in `Chart.js 1.0`. But when I run on browser I get the message "*xxxxxxxx.AddData is not a function*".

If can help this is the cose I am using https://jsfiddle.net/96u30Lht/ 
(I cannot find an url to chart.js 2 lib in my fiddle as a resource file this should be the reason why the canvas stays black)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using v2.0.0 from the dev branch (the file header reads 2.0.0-alpha, and the file I'm looking at is https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/f3eb6f4a433b4f34a582842dcf7b42f710861a7d/Chart.js)

You need to make a few changes to get your fiddle to work

---

**Make the Chart Type an Option**

I think v2.0 has only one constructor for all chart types. So

> chartdata = new Chart(ctx).Line({

should be

```
chartdata = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "line",
```

---

**Add a Type for the 2nd y-axis**

> scaleType: "linear"

to

```
type: "linear",
```

type is the property name. It doesn't cause any problem for the first y axis since it's optional there (your `scaleType: "linear"` on the first instance doesn't actually do anything and you can drop it)

---

**Remove the window.onload**

Your fiddle is already set to execute onLoad

---

**Change the Method Signature**

As far as I could see from the code, the method signature has changed for addData. It is now as follows (From the code) - **note that this could change anytime**

> // Add data to the given dataset
>   // @param data: the data to add
>   // @param {Number} datasetIndex : the index of the dataset to add to
>   // @param {Number} index : the index of the data
>   addData: function addData(data, datasetIndex, index)

So a better version of your setInterval would be

```
setInterval(function () {
    var latestlabel = chartlabel[6];

    chartdata.addData(12, 0, latestlabel);
    chartdata.addData(5, 1, latestlabel);
    chartdata.removeData(0, 0);
    chartdata.removeData(1, 0);

}, 7000);
```

---

https://jsfiddle.net/bsgc9tu7/

Comment: Btw, you can use rawgit to add files from github to jsfiddle

Comment: Ok! thank you, that's a little more complex than version 1. I hope this wont be the way in definitive version 2.0.

Comment: The documentation at that point has your version of the function call https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/dc58699ee7a741feba0cfce59d3a984f786f2d06/docs/01-Line-Chart.md. I assume it's just coming together.

Comment: I was using the same Chart.js 2.0.0 you used. Documentation sais to call the function as I did but this way does not work. I think documentation for this part is still the v1.0 and it is not been updated. Hopefully by the end of this month there'll be a new release

Comment: Hi added 2 lines so that even x label value is update during iteration:
`chartlabel.shift();chartlabel[6] = chartlabel[5]+1;`
https://jsfiddle.net/02j95u4h/